# Force WPF UI thread to update on a task

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, task, system.timers.timer

Currently this code works, I suppose it doesn't work as intended because I haven't figured out how to force update the UI thread for every Opacity change in the button.

```
    private void BtnStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        // Create a timer and add its corresponding event

        System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        timer.Elapsed += TimerFade_Elapsed;

        timer.Interval = 750;

        // Want a new thread to run this task on so
        // the main thread doesn't wait.

        Task task = new Task(() => timer.Start());
        task.Start();          
        //r.SingleThread();

    }

    private void TimerFade_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e) {
        // Access UI thread to decrease Opacity on a button from a different thread.

        Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
            if (btnStart.Opacity != 0.0) {
                btnStart.Opacity -= 1.0;
                // code here to force update the GUI.
            } else {
                System.Timers.Timer t;
                t = (System.Timers.Timer)sender;
                t.Stop();
            }
        });          

    }
```

The code works however visually, it doesn't. I suspect this has to do with me not updating the GUI when the changes are made.

Comment: Why don't you just simply use animations aka storyboards ?

Comment: @zackraiyan This is an excellent idea, I will look into this! However, I am still curious how to fix my original code to see where I was short.

Comment: Opacity has a range from 0.0 to 1.0 (0%..100%) and you go through this range with a single step. Not really fading ;o) Try it with btnStart.Opacity -= 1.0 / 20.0 for 20 steps

Comment: BTW you do not need a task here. The Timer.Start method will not really block anything

Comment: The code you provided is working fine. Just change the btnStart.Opacity -= 1.0; to btnStart.Opacity -= 0.1; and you will be able to see that button is updated slowly.

Comment: @SirRufo Good point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use a storyboard. Create one in the resource of the object(such as `Window`/`Page` or whatever you have) and then call the storyboard from code behind.

Here's a sample :

```
 <Window.Resources>
 <Storyboard x:Key="FadeAnim">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.4"/>
    </Storyboard>
 </Window.Resources>
```

And call it from code behind like this :

```
 Storyboard sb = this.FindResource("FadeAnim") as Storyboard;
 Storyboard.SetTarget(sb, this.YourButton);
 sb.Begin();
```

Comment: I just tried this, I might need this because writing all the code before is annoying. Excellent suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The code provided is working fine. The value of opacity range from 0 to 1. You are setting it to 1 in first go, which will make the button disappear on first refresh. If you can change the following line

> btnStart.Opacity -= 1.0;

To

> btnStart.Opacity -= 0.1;

You will be able to see the button fading slowly.

PS: The best way to do this would be using StoryBoard(DoubleAnimation) as mentioned by @zack

Comment: This is excellent. I completely forgot it's through 0-1.0, well done!